# Xcode 6.3 freezes for more than 2 minutes while typing objective C code

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, xcode6.3

Since I updated to Xcode 6.3 I experience very frequent freezes in XCode 6.3.

the reproduction steps are :

- click somewhere in a source/header file in the editor window
- the OS starts displaying this multicolor spinning icon for 2 minutes or more
- if I force quit XCode I get a bug report with always the same callstack with

[undoManager _endTopLevelGroupings] at top of it:

[image]

Comment: [Did you submit a bug report?](https://bugreport.apple.com/)

Comment: It also freezes on  opening 'Organizer' for me !!

Comment: @Bigood yes lot of crash report & also a bug report (20551543 )

Comment: I suspect the issue is related to a script we use here to unlock / check on perforce.

Comment: @N-AccessDev I just upgraded to 6.3 and see the same thing with our Perforce script. Have you found a workaround yet?

Comment: @EricMcNeill not yet, according to our data manager, this is a known problem with the perforce script . but we are waiting for a fix .

Comment: Issue is in the "tell application" itself.  `#++ osascript -ss -e 'tell application "xcode" to display dialog "{...file...}" with title "p4 edit ..."  buttons {"OK"} default button 1 giving up after "10" '
#+ OUTdlg='28:309: execution error: Xcode 7.2 got an error: AppleEvent timed out. (-1712)'`

Answer (score 3):

If you're using the same Perforce checkout script we are (from the Perforce web site), I tracked the problem down to the line where the script tells Xcode to show the feedback dialog:

```
osascript -e "tell application \"xcode\" to display dialog 
  (system attribute \"XC_RES\") buttons {\"OK\"} default button 
  1 giving up after (system attribute \"XC_TO\")"
```

Setting fb=0 disables this functionality, so you don't get the confirmation that the checkout was successful, but you don't get the hang either.

The same osascript command works fine for me from Terminal, not sure why Xcode has a problem with it running in this context. I can do without the feedback, so didn't track it down any further.

Comment: Thank you @Eric, this worked for me! The just started when I switched from Xcode 6.1 to Xcode 6.3 (and it happens with 6.4 too). My suspicion is that our corporate internet proxy is part of the equation. Do others experiencing this problem have Internet proxies?

Comment: I've swapped out this line for `osascript -e "display notification (system attribute \"XC_RES\") with title \"Perforce\""` to display a notification instead of a dialog box. Works well for me without the freeze.

Comment: Your `display notification` probably works more because you dropped telling xcode, and less because you switched from dialog to notification.